# some error happened in webpack.config.js

Tags: webpack-4, webpack.config.js

I am learning webpack 4, and I meet some errors .
here is my webpack.config.js

```
const path = require('path');
const webpack = require('webpack');

module.exports = {
  entry: './src/index.js',
  output: {
    filename: 'main.js',
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist')
  }
  module:{
    rules:[
      {test:/\.css$/, use:['style-loader','css-loader']}
    ]
  }
};
```

and here is error:

```
module:{
  ^^^^^^
SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
    at NativeCompileCache._moduleCompile    (/Users/meifei/Documents/learn-webpack/node_modules/v8-compile-cache/v8-compile-cache.js:226:18)
```

Comment: Typo, you are missing the comma after output:{...},

Comment: can anybody help me? I need some help .